# Запуск команд внутри скрипта без sudo

Tags: django, bash, sudo, pip

Имеет скрипт `deploy.sh`, в котором присутствует строка, которая должна ставить пакеты локально в виртуальное окружение:

```
echo -e "\nInstalling requirements..."
sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt"
```

Скрипт запускается командой `sudo ./deploy.sh`, следовательно, команда установки зависимостей выполняется как

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

и пакеты ставятся глобально, а не локально для текущего проекта.

Как сделать, чтобы команда выполнялась без `sudo`?

*Уточнение - скрипт содержит команды, которые требуют прав суперпользователя*

Comment: логичный ответ: запускайте скрипт без использования программы *sudo*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin он содержит команды, которые требуют прав суперпользователя. уточнил в вопросе

Comment: разбейте скрипт на два. или используйте программу *sudo* в тех случаях, где это необходимо.

Comment: А почему бы не написать sudo где надо внутри самого deploy.sh?

Comment: @andreymal интересно. а если скрипт запустит незнакомый человек с sudo? и задумка не сработает.

Comment: вы же пакеты в virtualenv ставите?

Comment: @NickVolynkin именно

Comment: Во-первых, можно воткнуть проверку, что скрипт запустили не через sudo, во-вторых, нечего давать чужим людям доступ к таким вещам :)

Comment: @andreymal скрипт необходим для автоматизации части команд по развертыванию сайта, если с ним работает команда разработчиков, один из них может запустить и от sudo. Проверку запуска без sudo попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выполнить конкретную команду от того пользователя, который запустил скрипт с sudo. Он доступен через переменную окружения `$SUDO_USER`. Сначала нужно будет активировать окружение, затем установить в него зависимости.

```
sudo -u $SUDO_USER ./env/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41366023/2790048

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51844/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-while1pass).